# ignore increacing font size of windows in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, fonts, size

In Windows it's possible to increase the size of on-screen fonts. We realized that too late and if a user does this our program is unusable, because they cannot see all texts and controls. We're bringing out a release and we do not have the time to fix this.
So: how can I disable or ignore this increasing from Windows application-wide? I tried setting autoscale to none, but it is not working. Isn't it possible to ignore that setting for the whole application? How can I do that?

I know that this is a wak solution because the user has a reason why they want to increase the font size. But we cannot fix this problem within two weeks, and want to provide an application somebody can use.

We are using VB.NET.

Comment: Tell the user not to increase the font size and get some glasses. Or write your application properly!

Comment: But if our application is the only one which cannot handle the increases, the user must change the settings everytime he uses our application. (And needs to log off for that!) Not so nice! I cannot urge the user to abandon that option only because our application cannot handle it!
We will do write that properly, but need more time than only two weeks. It's only a workaround for that single release.

Comment: Then they'll need to get some glasses for your app won't they.

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft the workaround is: 
Right-Click the Shortcut, click on the Compatibility Tab and Tick "Disable Display scaling on high DPI settings"

(Although this doesn't seem to always work.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no property or setting that you can adjust to tell a .NET application to ignore the settings you're talking about.  You will have to look for another option.